# Cannot find the array that causes "ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()"

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, dataframe

What I I trying to do is compare values.  If all the statements are true, then assign the value to a specific cell in the dataframe.

Here is my code:

```
if pd.isnull(ColValues)  or ColValues <  TPStartValue or ColValues > CndlHigh or ColValues < CndlLow or ColValues < PrevCndlHigh or ColValues < PrevCndlClose:
     ColNum += 1
else:
     DynamTPs.loc[TATicketNum,TimeColName] = TADF[DfName]['DateTime'].iloc[RowNum]
```

My dataframe name changes, so the dataframe names are stored in the TADF dictionary.

I have checked each variable with print(type()), and none are an array and also all are unique.

The error occurs on line 4 of this sample code, which is "DynamTPs.loc[TATicketNum,TimeColName] = TADF[DfName]['DateTime'].iloc[RowNum]".  I am not comparing variables.  I am assigning one.  So I believe the error is not with this line of code, but the variables that are sent to methods/functions (in Traceback).

I have checked each variable in this line.  All are unique and correct values (e.g. DfName is one value, TATicketNum - there is only one value in the dataframe, the dataframe's value for ['DateTime'].iloc[RowNum] there is only one value in the dataframe, RowNum is correct, ColNum is correct (as can be seen in below sample), etc.

The traceback is:

```
  File "C:\Users\Jonathan\OneDrive - Mazars in Oman\Trading\Systems\FibMatrix\Testing Trade Analysis\Python - RB Code\calculating dynamics v1-3-1.py", line 95, in FindDynamicTPSLs
    DynamTPs.loc[TATicketNum,TimeColName] = TADF[DfName]['DateTime'].iloc[RowNum]

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py", line 670, in __setitem__
    iloc._setitem_with_indexer(indexer, value)

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py", line 1765, in _setitem_with_indexer
    isetter(loc, value)

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py", line 1676, in isetter
    ser = self.obj._ixs(loc, axis=1)

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 2844, in _ixs
    label = self.columns[i]

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\multi.py", line 1902, in __getitem__
    if level_codes[key] == -1:

ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

Here is the TADF[DfName] sample (the RowNum when the error occurs is 28 and ColNum is 6, which in this sample is labeled _1m_21):

```
    DateTime             Open   High    Low     Close   Vol _1m_21  _1m_34
27  2020-07-01 20:25:00 1.8059  1.806   1.8059  1.806   81  1.806   1.8054
28  2020-07-01 20:26:00 1.806   1.8061  1.8058  1.8059  140 1.8061  1.8055
29  2020-07-01 20:27:00 1.8058  1.8058  1.8056  1.8056  120 1.806   1.8055
```

The sample for the DynamTPs I am trying to write into are (the TATicketNum to write into is 5650779; the column name is 'Dynamic TP-1 lane Time' :

```
        Dynamic TP-1 lane Time  Dynamic TP-1 lane Price  Dynamic TP-2 lane Time  Dynamic TP-2 lane Price                            
5650779   nan                        nan                      nan                  nan
5659605   nan                        nan                      nan                  nan
```

I appreciate any help!  Thanks in advance.

*****Update*****
When I print the type of "DynamTPs.loc[TATicketNum,TimeColName]" it says its a Series class.  Since this is the only thing that is a series type, I think this could be causing the problem.

I don't understand why it returns a series.  I downloaded the dataframe to excel, and I verified there is only one index number that matches TATicketNum and only one column label that matches "TimeColName".  I have printed the types of each of these variables and they are integer and string.  I also hard coded the loc[], to eliminate the variables as a problem. It still gives same error.

You can see above with the sample dataframe what it looks like and not duplicates.

I also switched from loc to iat and hard coded df.iat[0,0] and df.iat[0,1].  Then the values are entered in the DF correctly.

I also switched to "DynamTPs.loc[TATicketNum].at['Dynamic TP-1 lane Time']" (hard coded the string), and it also does not work.  No error message though.

When I try

```
TimeColIndex = DynamTPs.columns.get_loc('Dynamic TP-1 lane Time')
```

This is supposed to give me an integer, but it yeilds an array instead: [ True False False False False False False False] <class 'numpy.ndarray'>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why it works when loc does not, but using loc and at together worked.

```
DynamTPs.loc[TATicketNum].at['Dynamic TP-1 lane Time'] = ColTime
```

Comment: Isnt it because of the space between the words while the delimiter of python normally is space?  It thinks the program assumes that ''Dynamic TP-1 lane Time'' as 4 columns (each word is a separate column) and this is what cause the problem.

Comment: No. First it worked before when was using excel (now swithced to sQL).  Also, I replaced the spaces with _ and still get same error.

Answer (score 0):

1. use print after "ColNum += 1"  to find out in which  " pd.isnull(ColValues)  or ColValues" the problem happens.
2. print "TADF[DfName]['DateTime'].iloc[RowNum]" before line 4 to be sure about its type and value

Comment: I did this already.  1. error occurs when ColValue is at 28.  2. It prints correctly "2020-07-01 20:26:00"

Comment: So it seems the problem is not the code, bud the data. Can you check the data manually at line 28? (maybe two tabs are used and so on)

Comment: I did check; it is the sample data included in the above.  No duplicates.  Your comment made me realize I did not do a Type of the location I am assigning the timestamp to "DynamTPs.loc[TATicketNum,TimeColName]".  It says print = "Dynamic TP-1 lane Time    NaN".  Type = "Name: 5650779, dtype: object <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>"  The printed value is correct, the class is correct? or is this what is causing the problem?  I also tried changing it to "DynamTPs[TimeColName].iloc[TATicketNum]" and it gives error: "only integer scalar array can be be converted to scalar index."  Any thoughts

Comment: Is the Line 28, the first line that the program use "else" function?  The column name "'Dynamic TP-1 lane Time"  is weird as far as you use space between names.  each space represents a separate column.  Did you check this?

Comment: Can you explain more what you mean by the column name is " weird as far as you use space between names. each space represents a separate column. Did you check this"?  I didn't understand that.

Comment: Print the "DynamTPs" and check if everything is ok with this dataset.  As far as I understand, the name of the first column is " Dynamic TP-1 lane Time". Maybe, if the space is the delimiter, in the code you have 4 columns (named "Dynamic" and  "TP-1" and  "lane" and  "Time") instead of one!  But if the delimiter is defined correctly, then there will be no problem.

Answer (score 0):

The traceback indicates it occurs in the `iloc` method of

```
TADF[DfName]['DateTime'].iloc[RowNum]
```

What do you know about `RowNum`?  How about the row indices of the frame (or by now it may be Series)?

Comment: In the above sample data, that is the data that is when the error occurs.  So to answer your question, RowNum = 28.  And there is only one index number that is 28.  Also, I assigned "TADF[DfName]['DateTime'].iloc[RowNum]" to a varialbe and printed the type.  It says <class 'pandas._libs.tslibs.timestamps.Timestamp'>.  And the variable has the correct date.  So it seems to me that is not the series that is causing the error.